# EF Core 7 no definition for ExecuteUpdateAsync

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I have the following query in my project which is using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` 7.0.2:

```
await _context.Actions
    .Where(a => a.DateCreated < DateTime.Today && a.ActionType == (int)ActionTypes.ScoredAction && !a.DateCompleted.HasValue)
    .ExecuteUpdateAsync(b => b
        .SetProperty(x => x.DateCompleted, x => DateTime.Today)
        .SetProperty(x => x.ActionResultType, x => LeadScoringConstants.SystemClosed));
```

But when I try to build, it's saying that `IQueryable<ActionEntity>` doesn't contain a definition for `ExecuteUpdateAsync`.  Am I missing something here as the [documentation says it was added to EF Core 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#basic-executeupdate-examples)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`ExecuteUpdateAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.executeupdateasync?view=efcore-7.0) is part of the `RelationalQueryableExtensions`, do not forget to install corresponding nuget (i.e. [`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational)).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Will accept when it lets me